# GnuGPG python without binary and cross-platform

Tags: python, gnupg, pgp, python-gnupgp

I am looking for a python project to encrypt and decrypt files using the [GNU Privacy Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) protocol.

There exists packages like:

- [python-gnupg](https://pypi.org/project/python-gnupg/)
- [pretty-bad-protocol](https://pypi.org/project/pretty-bad-protocol/)

But they both needs to refer the a binary where the installation is platform dependant and it is not possible to verify lines as you can do it for a python script.

---

I am looking for a package that is able to encrypt and decrypt this standard with only python scripts. I am aware this will be much slower.

**Reasons are:**

- On Windows, the first use of gpg2.exe take a while and crash sometimes (for very extensive use)
- A python script can be opened by user to check for any malicious lines of codes
- It doesn't require any extra-step to install and can be used on any computeur that have python installed (I wan't to create a plugin on a software (QGIS) that contains a python install but it is possible to include only python scripts).

---

**My question**:

Where is it possible to find the GNUPG pseudo-code to recreate it from scratch in python OR a project of someone that already done it.